# How to add a hierarchical taxonomy to a content type

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I have a hierarchical taxonomy like below
[image: Hierarchical taxonomy]

In Drupal 7 there was a module name hierarchical select to achieve this. But it is no longer support for Drupal 8. Is there another way to add this to a content type, so a user can select an element from this taxonomy. I need that to be hierarchical.

Comment: No, there is no Hierarchical Select for D8 at this time.  If you need that module, use Drupal 7.

Comment: I don't need that module. But is there another way to add something hierarchical to a content type @PatrickKenny

Comment: You can create hierarchical taxonomies in D8 out of the box.  You can add them to a content type with an entity reference.  But, you won't have hierarchical selection in the widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look on [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) and [Client-side hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs) module.

**Simple hierarchical select**

> Simple hierarchical select defines a new form widget for taxonomy
>   fields to select a term by "browsing" through the vocabularies
>   hierarchy. The widget is available in node forms and as Views exposed
>   filter.
>
> This module has been inspired by Hierarchical select but is much
>   simpler (hence the name ;) ).

**Client-side hierarchical select**

> A simple client-side hierarchical select widget for taxonomy terms.
>
> The widget provides three settings:
>
> > Force selection of deepest level (If checked the user will be forced
> >     to select terms from the deepest level.)
> >
> > Parent (Allows to select a parent term to use only a subtree of a
> >     vocabulary for this field.)
> >
> > Labels per hierarchy-level